# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'Serial' error when used in a threaded function

Tags: python, multithreading, serial-port

I am trying to thread a function that opens a serial com and sends a message and then waits for the replay. Outside of the threaded function the serial works but in it I get this error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "MFC_Calv3_T.py", line 37, in serial
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', baudrate = 9600) # setup com to serial
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'Serial'
```

Here is the Function:

```
def serial():
 ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyACM0', baudrate = 9600) # setup com to serial
 ser.open()
 ser.write(str.encode('$GET DQ DC\r'))
 startTime = time.time()
 data = ser.readline()
 endTime = time.time()
 ser.close
 parts = data.split(",")
 Writer(startTime, endTime, parts)
```

My imports are:

```
import serial 
from serial import Serial
import threading
from threading import Thread
```

What am I missing?

Comment: don't use the same name for function `def serial()` as you have for `serial.Serial` - rename function to ie. `def get_serial()` and it will work.

Comment: you forgot `()` in `ser.close()`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @furas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the same name `serial` for module

```
import serial
```

and for function

```
def serial():
```

so `function` replaces `module` and this makes problem.

Rename function to ie. `def get_serial()` and it should resolve problem.